# Compare multiple columns in two sheets to get a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have limited working knowledge of Excel VBA macros.
I have two sheets called "Summary" and "Data"

- The Summary sheet has fixed rows and columns.
- The Data sheet has values in it.

I need to compare the Code, Company MRC number and Status of the Summary and Data sheets and if the fields match then get the corresponding value from Data sheet to Summary field.

[image: Excel]

Answer (score 0):

*My solution is based on the **attached Screen Shot**, where I found **only two common Columns between Sheets**, are*

**1. Code**

**2. Company MRC**

**I'm unable to find Status Of Summary & Data field.**

*I would like to suggest set of Macros to compare both Sheets for common data to be copied into another Sheet.*

```
Sub CompareRanges()

Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", "", Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Range B:", Type:=8)

For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
rng1Value = Rng1.Value

For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2

If rng1Value = Rng2.Value Then
Rng1.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0)
Exit For

End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. Respond both **Input Boxes** with an appropriate Data Range from both Sheets to be compared.
2. Macro will **highlight duplicate Data** in Sheet 1(Data Sheet) with **Red color**.
3. **RUN** the below written Macro to Copy Duplicate Data.
4. Copy both Macros as **Standard Module**.

**Edited:**

*Do the following to avoid using the second Macro:*

1. Select the data range in `DATA Sheet` & apply **Auto Filter**.
2. **Filter** Rows in *Red Color*.
3. **Copy** Filtered Rows.
4. Place the Cell pointer at required Cell & apply **Pastes Special** then Click **Value**.

   ```
   Sub CopyRedRows()

   Dim wks As Worksheet
   Dim wNew As Worksheet
   Dim lRow As Long
   Dim lNewRow As Long
   Dim x As Long

   Set wks = Sheets("Data")
   lRow =  wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 

     Set wNew = Sheets("Summary")
     lNewRow = 10

     For x = 1 To lRow
       If wks.Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
         wks.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Copy wNew.Cells(lNewRow, 1)
         lNewRow = lNewRow + 1
       End If
     Next

   End Sub
   ```
5. *`Sheet Name`, `RGB Color Code` & `lNewRow` values are editable.*